# Difference Aut(F:K) and G(F:K)

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

What is the difference between the group of automorphisms that keep a subfield fixed versus the Galois group keeping the same field fixed? Are Aut{F:K} and G(F/K) just two ways of writing the same thing?

Comment: Yup as far as convention goes, that's the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $\operatorname {Aut}(F/K)$ may always be used.
A healthy habit is to replace it by $\operatorname {Gal}(F/K)$ only in the case that the extension $F/K$ is Galois: it is a bit unaesthetic to talk of the Galois group of an extension that isn't Galois...
Anyway this restriction of the use of $\operatorname {Gal}(F/K)$ to case of  Galois extensions  is the convention  explicitly adopted by Bourbaki and by Milne [in his online course](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf) (Definition 3.9, last line of page 37) and , as far as I am aware, by Serre, Grothendieck and his school, and many others.

Comment: Beyond that, @GeorgesElencwajg, OP did not specify that the extension was algebraic. We may (and do!) speak of the group of automorphisms of $k(t)$ over $k$, $t$ being a transcendental element, but this is nothing like a Galois group.

Comment: Dear @Lubin: I don't understand what you mean. A Galois extension is by definition  algebraic, so algebraicity did not not have to be mentioned explicitly in my answer, which is exclusively based on the dichotomy Galois/not Galois.

Comment: I certainly did not mean to disagree with anything you said, so I retreat only partially.

Comment: While I do not disagree with what you write, I want to remark that Jacobson (in Basic Algebra I) uses $\operatorname{Gal} E/F$ for the group of $F$-automorphisms of $E$ irrespective of whether the extension $E/F$ is Galois or not. As a loyal disciple/devout believer of that Holy Tome I use that notation myself. I would like to check what Artin's lecture notes use, but my copy is currently buried in a moving box. We are ok as long as we're aware that there are different conventions in use here, too.

Comment: You are absolutely right, dear @Jyrki, we should certainly take in consideration the terminology adopted by a great mathematician like Jacobson, for whom I share your admiration. I would *a priori* not criticize anybody for calling *Galois group* the automorphism group of an arbitrary field extension, but since Avatrin explicitly asked, I gave my opinion and arguments for it. But of course I'm quite ok with the competing point of view.

Comment: @Jyrki: by the way, I really appreciate your enthusiasm about Jacobson's Holy Tome. I find the too widespread *blasé* atitude of our colleagues toward admirable mathematicians regrettable when compared to the cries and jumps of joy of our beloved little one when we told her we would take her to a live concert of [Violetta](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violetta_Live) in October, as a birthday present.